# Voice modifier software

Tags: gratis, audio, voice-recording, audio-editing

I'm looking for a software able to modify my voice as I speak. I'm mastering rpg via Mumble and it would be quite a useful bonus to the ambiance to make me sound like a robot, for instance.

So far, I found [MorphVox](http://www.screamingbee.com) which answers perfectly my need. However, the free version is too limited and the pro version price is prohibitive.

To sum up, I need a software that

- morphs voice (for instance, make it sound like a robot) in live
- is able to be used as input source for Mumble
- is free
- works on Windows or Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have never tried any of these but maybe worth a check:

[Voxal Voice Changer](http://www.nchsoftware.com/voicechanger/)

- Morph voice in real time(Includes robot, girl, boy, alien, ethereal, echo and many more)
- Gratis
- Works on Windows and MAC OS X

  > Powerful, real-time voice changing software
  >
  > Modify, change and disguise your voice in any application or game that
  >   uses a microphone to add another dimension of creativity. *From ‘Girl’
  >   to ‘Alien’, the voice changing options are limitless.*
  >
  > *Create voices for online video games, avatars and podcasts*. Voice
  >   disguiser for anonymity over the radio or internet. Change voices for
  >   voiceovers and other audio projects. Small download installs in
  >   seconds. Voxal works behind the scenes intercepting audio from your
  >   microphone before it goes to your applications, so you don't need to
  >   change any configurations or settings in other programs. Simply
  >   install and start creating voice distortions in minutes.
  >
  > Voice Changing Features:
  >
  > -Effects can be applied to existing files
  >   -*Apply effects in real time to an audio input* (e.g., microphone)
  >   -Load and save effect chains for voice modification
  >   -Vocal effect library includes robot, girl, boy, alien, ethereal, echo and many more
  >   -Create unlimited, custom voice effects
  >   -Works with all existing applications and games
  >   -Output the changed audio to speakers to hear the effects live
  >   -Low CPU usage will not interfere with other running applications
  >   -Simple and intuitive interface

[AV Voice Changer Software DIAMOND](http://av-voice-changer-software-diamond.software.informer.com/)

- Morph voice in real time(different tones of the voice, such as surprise, happiness, languor, rage, etc.)
- Gratis
- Works on Windows and MAC OS X

  > V Voice Changer Software DIAMOND is a program for *changing your voice
  >   in real time*. This tool includes various effects developing different
  >   tones of the voice, such as surprise, happiness, languor, rage, etc.
  >   This software enables you to record your voice, analyze the quality
  >   and compare it with other voices. Then you can add different effects
  >   to the recording, change female voice to, for example, male or
  >   nonhuman. You can also create a nickvoice, which represents a unique
  >   combination of voice properties with the help of a number of voice
  >   modifying functions - voice analyzer, parody mixer, voice comparator,
  >   music morpher, voice recorder, background effects. The majority of
  >   sound effects and unusual sounds are available for free download at
  >   the developer's homepage.

**I am no sound engineer but I guess these can work too if you have experience using the autotune.**

- [Autotalent v0.2](http://tombaran.info/autotalent.html) ([Talentedhack](https://code.google.com/p/talentledhack/) plugin for this more available online)
- [GVST](http://www.gvst.co.uk/index.htm)

Comment: While I found these softwares useful (and I thank you for that ;) ), you may want to improve your answer by specifying how each software meets the requirements

Comment: @fxm okay i have included all the requirements in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

[Fake Voice - Free Voice Changer](http://www.fakewebcam.com/Free-Voice-Changer-Fake-Voice.asp) should meet your needs:

1. It will morph your voice in real time.
2. It has a specific setting for sounding robotic.
3. It is free of charge (gratis).
4. It works on Windows.

The only requirement I'm not sure about is if can be used as an input source for Mumble, but I don't see any reason why not as long as your sound input for Mumble is located in close proximity to the output of Fake Voice.

Fake Voice is very easy to use.  You can modify the output in real-time using standard sliders.  Here is a screenshot of the UI:

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll take a look tonight !

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback ! I took a look but didn't manage to make it work

Comment: This will also try to install Fake Webcam. After installation, it needs to be registered with an email. After that, the free registration code is only activated if you click the Facebook like button. Not serious...